# Can't get static property to work in emberjs class using property bindings

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to create a static property in an ember object (all instances should share the same property and react when it changes).  In my case I have 4 different instances, if any of these instances changes the `refresh` property I want all 4 instances to react to it.

I have found that the `refresh` binding only executes for the current instance whereby I want it to execute for all instance given it is a static property.

```
        enabled : function() {
           ...
        }.property('refresh'), <----- this only executes for the current instance


        selectionChanged : function() { 
            ...
            this.incrementProperty('refresh');
        }.observes('selection')
```

I have tried creating the the `refresh` property using a mixin

```
    var AbstractControlMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
        refresh : 0
    });

    var AbstractControl = Ember.Object.extend(AbstractControlMixin,{
       ...
    });
```

an using the reopen technique

```
var AbstractControl = Ember.Object.extend({
    ...
});

AbstractControl.reopen({
            refresh : 0
});
```

but neither is working.

Comment: That isn't a static property.  I'm guessing you're basing that statement based off of the statement on this page: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/

Comment: Yes, and elsewhere on the internet that say that the above methods apparently create static properties.  Are they all incorrect?

Comment: They are probably referring to the method as being static, but the context is definitely instance based.  So the method doesn't get copied to each and every instance, but it definitely is an instance base context and value.

Comment: I've never read that documentation before, but it's just wrong.  The method being static is different than the property being static.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a reference to an object to your class and this will be a static reference shared amongst all of your instances.  You need to be careful though, if you were to make it into a mixin it would be shared across every single thing that used it, it wouldn't be different for each class.

```
var klass = Em.Object.extend({
  name:'',
  refresh:{
    value:0
  },
  changed: function(){
    console.log('refresh ' + this.get('name'));
  }.observes('refresh.value')
});

var k1 = klass.create({name:'k1'});
var k2 = klass.create({name:'k2'});

k1.incrementProperty('refresh.value'); // this will fire changed for all instances
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yucupofosu/1/edit?html,js,output